# How to read indoor positioning equipment date by ros

Tags: ros, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to read  indoor positioning equipment date to ROS.The indoor positioning equipment called Ubisense which can publish location date(like three-dimensional coordinate x, y, z) to  local area network.So I want knew about how ROS read the  indoor positioning equipment date.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241740/how-to-read--indoor-positioning-equipment--date-by-ros/) by [chenlee](https://answers.ros.org/users/27694/chenlee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-08-15

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-08-15**:
You realize that you ask how to read data from your device without telling which device you have?

**Comment by [chenlee](https://answers.ros.org/users/27694/chenlee/) on 2016-08-15**:
My device is a indoor positioning equipment called Ubisense which can publish location date(like three-dimensional coordinate x, y, z),but I don't know how ROS read it.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-08-15**:
Could you please update your question? It's completely useless in it's current version.

**Comment by [chenlee](https://answers.ros.org/users/27694/chenlee/) on 2016-08-15**:
Thanks.I thought there need a API so I can use directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`Location date`? You mean `Location data`, right?

In the ROS Navigation Stack, the basic tf is `map->odom->base_link`, the encoders in your robot can get odometry infomation, from which you can get the pose of `base_link` relative to `odom`.

And with `Ubisense`, you can get the position of `base_link` relative to `map`. With this position, you can adapt `map->odom` to make your robot's position right.

I guess `Ubisense` uploads the robot position to your computer(which runs ROS) through USB or Serial Port. After reading that info, you need to write a `Publisher` program to publish your position to ROS(say topic `/Ubisense/Pose`). This position info should in the `geometry_msgs/Pose` format.(or other similar format).

And then, you need a `tf` program which subscribes the topic `/Ubisense/Pose`, and broadcast the tf `map->odom`.

Good Luck.

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1